# Testing the controller which returns response entity

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller, junit, entity, response

I have following the controller which accepts post request and returns Response Entity with body

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService UserService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ResponseUser>> navigationTree(@RequestBody(required=false) UserDataRequest request) {
        return UserService.sendEntries(request);
    }
}
```

This is the test I wrote I for it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class UserControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService UserServiceMock;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void returnTopLevel() throws Exception {


        String expectedJson = "[{\"id\":\"11\",\"name\":\"11\"},{\"id\":\"22\",\"name\":\"22\"}]";
        MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(post("/all")
                 .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .content("")
                 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                 .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

        String actualJson = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();

       // System.out.println(result);

        //assertThat(Objects.equals(expectedJson, actualJson)).isTrue();

         verify(UserServiceMock,times(1)).sendEntries(null);

    }
}
```

I want to compare string received in response body to expected string.

1. I tried the string comparison but it's not working

Errors :

```
    assertThat(Objects.equals(expectedJson, actualJson)).isTrue();
```

and     actualjson is empty.

What are the other ways?

Comment: Firstly explain not working.. Please paste the actualJson and the result. You can compare individual values using `.jsonPath`, but not sure if you can compare entire json. Check this out https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-test-how-to-test-a-json-array-in-jsonpath/

Comment: Edited the question.  "for resonpse entity .jsonpath is not working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the `UserService` to return something before executing `this.mockMvc.perform`.  Something like this:

```
when(UserServiceMock.sendEntries(null)).thenReturn(expectedResponceEntity);
```

So just construct the expected response then mock `UserService` to return it.

Comment: It's working. But ,Why do we have to mock user service?

Comment: You dont have to mock it, but you did mock it with line `@MockBean`.  If you do not want to mock it but still do a veirfy on it, then consider `@SpyBean`.  With `@SpyBean` you reserve the option to mock without actually having to do it, and can still do a verify on it.  https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy